# How to convert ULONG64 to pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2013, dbghelp

I have an `ULONG64` variable from `SYMBOL_INFO` structure that contains virtual address represented as 18446744073709551572 value and I need to convert it to the `void*` so I can pass it to the `ReadProcessMemory` function.

If I just do

```
reinterpret_cast<void*>(pSymInfo->Address)
```

it gives me FFFFFFD4.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That value converts to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD4` in hex, so it looks like your cast is simply truncating that to 32-bits - suggesting you only have a 32-bit build. As a signed value it equals `-44`. Either way it's not a valid pointer - where did the value come from?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter It came from the following code -- http://pastie.org/9728688

Comment: That doesn't look like a real address. Unless you provide code and details and context, you aren't likely to get much more than has been written above

Comment: @David Heffernan You can see it here -- http://pastie.org/9728688

Comment: Offsite code. Not ideal. We don't know anything about it. Which line you are referring to. What the code is attempting to do. Why you expect to fit that value into a 32 bit type. Etc. You are aware that your process is 32 bit right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the `reinterpret_cast` is not working as it should but I usually use `ULongToPtr` to do these kind of things.

```
ReadProcessMemory(process, ULongToPtr(virtual_address), &content, sizeof content, nullptr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ULongToPtr returns the same value